# Python: Even after an if runs, the else still runs as well

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a game of Go Fish in Python. But I've stumbled onto a little problem that I can't seem to figure out how to deal with.

There is a human player (player 0) and three computer players (from 1-3). The human player goes first and chooses a target player. And then a card rank (for example, the player could target player two and choose jacks, then the computer would have to give the player all its jacks).

What I have so far is below but the problem I'm having is right at the bottom of the code. So far, the code generates a deck, creates hands for every player, and then shows the player his/her cards. Then the player is asked which computer player he/she wants to target as well as the rank of cards.

The problem I'm having is with the last set of lines (the def player_0_hitman) at the bottom of the code. Any help would be much appreciated. There are basically three issues I'm having problems with.

1. Basically, my code is ignoring the if's and else's. I don't get why. Everything appears to be positioned correctly, but for some odd reason, even after an if, the program also runs the else as well.
2. the "hit" is not being returned. Even though in the definition, I have the hit set to hit = hit - 1 for the last else, it still reruns the whole definition again as if it the hit was 1
3. I'm trying to use the count line to count how many cards are being transferred so the program will tell the player how many cards he gains when he gets a successful guess but I only get a statement saying I got 1 card each time no matter what (whether I get no cards or I get more than one).

I understand the basics of what I need to do but I can't seem to get a working code for this. I've tried changing the "for" to "if" but I get all sorts of errors so I don't think that will work. Then I tried converting "hit" into another code before entering the definition, changing it while inside, then converting it back before returning it but that also seems to do nothing, and I still get the same issues. I tried getting rid of the for but I get an error involving "card.

```
import random

def SetDeck():
    suitList = ["s", "c", "d", "h"]
    rankList = ["a", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "t", "j", "q", "k"]
    deck = []
    for suite in range(4):
        for rank in range(13):
            deck.append(rankList[rank]+suitList[suite])
    return deck

def Shuffle(deck):
    nCards = len(deck)
    for i in range(nCards):
        j = random.randint(i,nCards-1)
        deck[i], deck[j] = deck[j], deck[i]
    return deck

def GetTopCard(shuffledDeck):
    return shuffledDeck.pop(0)

def DealInitialCards(nPlayers,nCards,shuffledDeck):
    playersCards = [["" for j in range(nCards)] for i in range(nPlayers)]
    for j in range(nCards):
        for i in range(nPlayers):
            playersCards[i][j] = GetTopCard(shuffledDeck)
    return playersCards

def Sort(cards):
    rankString = "a23456789tjqk"
    swapped=True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(cards)-1):
            if rankString.find(cards[i][0])>rankString.find(cards[i+1][0]):
                cards[i],cards[i+1]=cards[i+1],cards[i]
                swapped = True
    return


def ShowCards(player,cards):
    print("\n****************************************************")
    print("************Player "+str(player)+" has**************")
    print("****************************************************\n")
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        print(cards[i]),
    print("\n")
    return

def ShowMessage(msg):
    print("****************************************************")
    print(str(msg))
    print("****************************************************\n")
    return

def remove_suits(player):
    new_hand = []
    for card in pHands[player]:
        new_card = card[0]
        new_hand.append(new_card)
    return new_hand

def choosing_target():
    target_player = raw_input ("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)")
    while target_player.isdigit() == False or 1 > int(target_player) or 3 < int(target_player):
        print "Error: Must type a valid player id (from 1 to 3)"
        target_player = raw_input ("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)")
    target_player = int(target_player)
    return target_player

def target_rank():
    target_card = raw_input ("What rank are you seeking? (" + str(",".join(new_hand)) + ")")
    while target_card not in new_hand:
        print "Error: Must type one of the follow valid single character card ranks"
        print str(",".join(new_hand))
        target_card = raw_input ("What rank are you seeking? (" + str(",".join(new_hand)) + ")")
    return target_card

print("~"*70)
print("~"*25+"WELCOME TO GO FISH!"+"~"*26)
print("~"*70)

nPlayers = 4
nCards = 10
deck = SetDeck()
sDeck = Shuffle(deck[:])
pHands = DealInitialCards(nPlayers,nCards,sDeck)
Sort(pHands[0])
ShowCards(0,pHands[0])

hit = 1

while hit == 1 :
    ShowMessage("TURN: Player 0, its your turn.")
    target_player = choosing_target()
    new_hand = remove_suits(0)
    target_card = target_rank()
    ShowMessage("Target: Player " + str(target_player) + " is being targeted for the rank <" + str(target_card) + ">")
    temp_hit = player_0_hitman(hit)
    print "hit = " + str(hit)

def player_0_hitman(hit):
    for card in pHands[target_player]:
        if target_card[0] == card[0]:
            count = pHands[target_player].count(card)
            pHands[0].append(card)
            pHands[target_player].remove(card)
            ShowMessage("HIT: " + str(count) + " card(s) transferred")
        else:
            top_card = GetTopCard(sDeck)
            pHands[0].append(top_card)
            if top_card[0] == target_card[0]:
                ShowMessage("HIT: LUCKILY Player 0 has fished up a rank <" + str(top_card[0]) + ">!!!")
            else:
                ShowMessage("MISS: You fished up the rank <" + str(top_card[0]) + ">")
                hit = hit - 1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I noticed you wrote your own sort method. Python has a built in one called `sorted` that you can call on any collection.

Comment: Since suits don't matter, why even have them?  Traditional go fish is based on pairs so you would only need to transfer one card at a time.

Comment: It's a modified version of Go Fish. There's a "traditional" way as you've highlighted but the game has gone through a long history and various cultures so there are many different interpretations of it. This is just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following:

```
if any(card[0] == target_card for card in pHands[target_player]):
    transfer_cards = card[0] == target_card in pHands[target_player]
    del card[0] == target_card in pHands[target_player]
    if any(card[0] == target_card for card in pHands[0]):
        pHands[0].extend(transfer_cards)
```

with

```
# Make a copy of the list so we don't modify it while enumerating it [:]
for i, card in enumerate(pHands[target_player][:]):
    # Example: "Do you have a seven?"
    if target_card[0] == card[0]:
        pHands[0].append(target_card)
        del pHands[target_player][i]
```

---

And a quick tip first to change this block of code to eliminate hard coded indices:

```
for suite in range(4):
     for rank in range(13):
         deck.append(rankList[rank]+suitList[suite])
```

to

```
for suite in suitList:
     for rank in rankList:
         deck.append(rank+suit)
```

Comment: Hmm....for some reason, the last line: del pHands[target_player][target_card] gives an error

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 0):

Some errors I see (my apologies if they're already in your code):

- Your variable target_card only holds the value of the card, not the suit. You may need to parse the full card in two, since those include both a suit and a value
- That's not a proper use of the del command; you don't need to set it equal to anything or test for an equality.

It would also be helpful to post what errors you got, to help us troubleshoot.

Also, I don't think this is how Go Fish is played..

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no idea what GoFish is or how its played, but I am answering this from a Python perspective.

Matt gave you the answer for your if statement, but I see you are duplicating a few things that are available with Python.

Using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) you can replace your `SetDeck` method, and as others have mentioned there is `sort` and `sorted` available already.  This and a few other refactorings and you end up with the following, as a starter:

```
import itertools
import random

def create_deck(suits, cards):
      return list(''.join(i).upper() for i in itertools.product(suits, cards))

def shuffle_deck(deck):
    return random.shuffle(deck)

def get_top_card(deck):
    return shuffle_deck(deck)[0]

def deal_cards(players, cards, deck):
    player_cards = {}
    for i in players:
        # For each player, shuffle the deck
        # then get as many cards as the cards
        # variable from the deck
        player_cards[i] = list(itertools.repeat(get_top_card(deck), cards))
    return player_cards

def show_message(message):
    border = '*'*52 
    return '{0}\n{1:*^52}\n{2}\n'.format(border, message, border)

def show_cards(player, cards):
    print(show_message('Player {0} has'.format(player)))
    print('\n'.join(cards[player]))

def remove_suits(player, cards, suit):
    new_cards = []
    for i in cards[player]:
       if not i.startswith(suit):
           new_cards.append(i)

    cards[player] = new_cards
    return cards

def choosing_target():
    choice = raw_input("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)")
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error, you must enter a number')
        choosing_target()
    if 1 < choice < 4:
        print('Please enter a number between 1 and 3')
        chooing_target()
    return choice  

def target_rank(ranks):
    ranks_choice = ','.join(ranks)
    choice = raw_input("What rank are you seeking? ({0})".format(ranks_choice))
    while choice not in ranks:
        print("You much choose from one of the following\n")
        print("{0}".format(ranks_choice))
        choice = raw_input("What rank are you seeking? ({0})".format(ranks_choice))
    return choice
```

Things I have updated:

1. Using `itertools.product` will give you the combinations you need:

   ```
   >>> suitList = ["s", "c", "d", "h"]
   >>> rankList = ["a", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "t", "j", "q", "k"]
   >>> list(''.join(i).upper() for i in itertools.product(suitList, rankList))
   ['SA', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'ST', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'CA', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'CT', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK', 'DA', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'DT', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DK', 'HA', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'HT', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HK']
   ```
2. Using the [format mini language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples), you can optimize your banner creation:

   ```
   >>> print('{0:~^70}'.format('Welcome to go fish!'))
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Welcome to go fish!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```
3. Using `itertools.repeat`, you can optimize your loop a bit:

   ```
   >>> def foo(i):
   ...    return i
   ...
   >>> list(itertools.repeat(foo('x'), 3))
   ['x', 'x', 'x']
   ```
4. You don't need `str` in this line `print str(",".join(new_hand))`, because you are creating a string by joining the list with `','`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind. But are those features added in newer versions of Python? I'm using Python 2.7.

Also, Matt's answer was to a previous question, which I've modified over. The only problem I'm having right now is with the very last definition.

Comment: No, all this will run in Python 2.7

Comment: Would you happen to have any input on the main issue I'm having? The player_0_hitman(hit) definition.

Comment: I have no idea what that method is supposed to be doing since I don't know the game GoFish. Perhaps adding some comments to your source code would help. To start off with though, you seem to have some basic indentation problems; and only one return statement, which is indented leaving some execution paths with an implicit return value of `None`.

Comment: I'll try to explain the main issue I'm having as accurately as possible.

Basically, I've changed the indentations around but the main issue I get is that the GetTopCard(sDeck) line is being run multiple times for some reason. So when I run the program, I get "MISS: You fished up the rank......" multiple times and my list pHands[0] is increased by several number combinations when I only want it to increase by one.

I also updated that last definition in my main code.

Comment: From what I understand, human player selects a target; human player selects a suit, target's hand is removed of all cards matching that suit - what's next? What is a "hit"?

Comment: Oh, hit is just my choice of wording to dictate when the while loop would end. 

Basically, if the human player chooses a card rank that is in the target's hand, the "hit" counter will stay at 1 and the loop will run again. If the human player gets it wrong, he/she gets another chance by drawing a random card from the GetTopCard function. If that drawn card is the same rank (ex. 2-9, t, j, q, k, a), once again, loop will run again. But if the drawn rank is different, the hit counter which is at 1 will drop to 0. And since the while loop requires hit to be 1 to rerun, it will stop.